# Android - Change Locale (Language)

Tags: android, locale

I'm trying to add language controller meaning changing the language of my app.

I've added 4 flags (ImageView), and whenever I press the flag I want, I want the app to change the language depennding on that flag.

[image: Main Menu]

The apps start out being English, and when I press the Danish falg, the language DOES switch to Danish, but whenever I want to change back to english, nothing happens.

I've made several strings.xml files in their own value folder

```
value-en/strings.xml
value-dk/strings.xml
```

**Method changing language:**

```
english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("en");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
});
```

*`english` is my variable for the ImageView*

Comment: Your code is absolutely correct. What is the problem occurring by run this code.???

Comment: The language simply doesn't change. It stays Danish

Comment: Use "en_US" instead of "en" in the local.

Comment: The problem just changed: None of my buttons work when I change the language to Danish. Do I need to tell it to use my Activity class aswell?

Comment: Some more code would be helpfull

Comment: What more do you need? This is all the code being run?

Comment: I have written one solution for you with code below.

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution.

In order to save the `onClickListener()` on my other components, I need to refresh the activity, posted below:

**To restart the activity**

I simply made a method like the one below:

```
//Restarts the activity after changing the languagse
private void RestartActivity(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And everytime I change the language, I run the method:

```
english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("en");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RestartActivity(); //Run the method as the last thing
    }
});
```

For some reason the listeners doesn't see mto stay, but this solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tested below code and it is working as per my consideration. Check this it will help you or not. 
Call this method on your click listener and pass locale string as a parameter.

private void setDeviceDefaultLanguage(String languageToLoad) {

```
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
}
```